# How to convert rows into columns in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query:

```
select ec.examcentrename as ecentre, ss.subjectcode, count(ss.studentsubjectdetailsid) as students from studentexamdetails se
join studentsubjectdetails ss
on se.studentid=ss.studentid and se.semesterid=ss.semesterid and se.examyearid=ss.examyearid
join examcentre ec on se.examcentreid=ec.examcentreid
where se.examyearid=8 and se.semesterid=2
group by ec.examcentrename,ss.subjectcode
order by ec.examcentrename,ss.subjectcode
```

this returns:
ecentre                SubjectCode              Students
Examcentrea          Subjectcodea             10
Examcentreb          Subjectcodea             1
Examcentreb          Subjectcodeb             8
Examcentreb          Subjectcodec             7
Examcentrec          Subjectcodea             8
Examcentrec          Subjectcodey             8
and so on....

Basically it returns me the
`examcentrename,subjectcode and numberofstudents`

I would like to convert this data into columns this format:

```
Examcentrea   SubjectCodea 10
Examcentreb   Subjectcodea 1  Subjectcodeb 8  Subjectcodec 7
Examcentrec   Subjectcodea 8  Subjectcodey 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PIVOT` operator. Please read this link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

> You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT relational operators to change a
>   table-valued expression into another table. PIVOT rotates a
>   table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column
>   in the expression into multiple columns in the output, and performs
>   aggregations where they are required on any remaining column values
>   that are wanted in the final output. UNPIVOT performs the opposite
>   operation to PIVOT by rotating columns of a table-valued expression
>   into column values.

It contains all neccessary information and examples how to use it.